# Bit Torrent Sync, EC2 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, bittorrent-sync

I am new here and have tried searching but could not get any answers.

I have set up Bit Torrent Sync on an EC2 micro instance with EBS attached.

The server is in Sydney which is where I spend most of my time.

However I do travel a fair bit and would like to have more locations where the files are located.

Is there a way to do this without setting up another EC2 server? I was thinking CloudFront may be helpful here but I do not know how to set it up.

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a couple of ways you can do this:

1. You can setup S3 with Cloudfront. Basically, you copy your static files to an S3 bucket (Global works good) and then say from the AWS console you can go to CloudFront and create a distribution for that specific bucket.
2. Point the the CloudFront distribution to the web server where you are hosting your files (Assuming you are using HTTP or HTTPs)

You can also specify a custom CNAME Record that you can use on your domain to point to the CloudFront distribution.

Furthermore for improved performance you can use: `All Edge Locations` when creating your CloudFront distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Rico, thanks for that. However is there an issue with Bit Torrent Sync using a priority protocol and not actually HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: CloudFront will not work then, unless you can find a way to server your files through HTTP/HTTPS. There might be ways if you are just serving files.

Comment: Can you torrent files hosted on cloud front or do you need to directly go to S3 to use it?

Comment: You need to use S3.